# Node.js: How to programmatically determine asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, intel-edison

I'd like to be able to take a function that doesn't take a callback and determine if it will execute asynchronously.

In particular, I'm working with Node.js on the Intel Edison using [mraa](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/mraa), and it has native C++ implemented functions like `i2c.readReg(address)` that doesn't accept a callback.

1. How can I determine if a function is blocking the processor for other system processes?
2. How can I determine if other JS can run in the interim?

Or am I not even approaching this the right way?

Comment: You can’t do this. To know whether it’s the right approach, we’d have to know what you’re approaching. Why do you need to it programmatically?

Comment: By doing it programmatically, I'm doing my research before I make a callback feature request or pull. If it's a non-blocking function call (since it dives down to some system level functions), then there might not really be much of a need for callbacks.

Comment: If it was pure JS then you could probably check whether the returned value was a promise. However, since you're using native functions this might not be possible. Hence, I have to go with @minitech on this one. You can't determine programmatically whether a function is asynchronous.

Comment: It was my assumption that C/C++ code always blocks and if you want asynchronicity then you have to use `fork`/`join` or some other form of threading. If so, then I would assume that all your native C++ functions would be synchronous since the asynchronicity would be handled by `fork`/`join` within the C++ code itself (i.e. it wouldn't return until the asynchronous operation completed). Am I correct?

Comment: @AaditMShah - C/C++ does not always block.  There is non-blocking IO in the Win32 API, for example.  Socket IO has long had a non-blocking way to use it in all platforms.

Comment: @jfriend00 My point is, doesn't non-blocking IO in C/C++ use `fork`/`join`? If so, wouldn't the C/C++ function handle the asynchronicity internally and appear to be synchronous to the JavaScript code?

Comment: Not fork/join - non-blocking and threading are two separate concepts. Generally when someone says non-blocking they mean single threaded. The heard of non-blocking I/O is the select/poll/epoll system call (Windows also have their proprietary overlapped stuff which does the same). At the heart of every javascript interpreter is a select/poll/epoll loop.

Comment: @AaditMShah - There is certainly non-blocking IO in C/C++ that does not use fork/join so I think your assumption there is a bit wrong.  The first version of the Netscape browser on Windows was all non-blocking, non-threaded, single process networking.

Comment: @srlm: You should be looking at documentation for that, then. Anyway, the reason why it’s not possible is that there’s no concrete difference between synchronous and asynchronous – even asynchronous code could queue a task synchronously.

Answer (score 8):

You can't really determine asynchronicity programmatically.  It should be clear from the API presented because if it's asynchronous, then there pretty much have to be signs of that in the way you use it.

If a function is asynchronous, then that means that it does not directly return the result from the function call because the function returns before the result is ready.  As such, the **documentation for the function** has to tell you how to obtain the result and if it's asynchronous there has to be another mechanism such as:

1. a callback function you can pass in
2. a returned promise
3. some sort of event listener on the object
4. some other notification mechanism
5. examine the code of the function
6. function naming convention (such as the suffix "Sync" that node.js uses)

If the function directly returns the result of the function call, then it is synchronous and other Javascript code will not run during that call.

---

If a function is not already asynchronous, the only way to turn that into an async operation is to run it in a different thread or process and marshall the value back to the main thread (calling some sort of callback in the main thread when the value is ready).

Answer (score 1):

you can analyze js transformed into an abstract syntax tree with a tool like acorn. you could check to see if function arguments get executed. however, it would be difficult to tell if it was being executed as a callback or for some other purpose. you could also check to see if blocking functions were being called.

i'm not sure if this would get you all the way there but it would be a handy tool to have.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not exactly a solution**, just a hint on cases which might be indeed a solution.

Many franeworks or libraries, define functions which can work either synchronously or asynchronously, depending on whether the last function argument (the callback) is given.

For example:

```
function dummy_sync_or_async(data, callback)
{
  if (callback)
  { 
     // call async code
     //..
     callback(result);
  }
  else
  {
    // call sync code
    // ..
    return result;
  } 
}
```

Then one can check the number of arguments received (for example if working as a proxy to these function methods) and check these against the function signature (i.e [function.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length))

Then one can decide whether the function is called in sync or async mode.