# How can I tell if a function from an npm module is asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, npm, browserify

My background is in systems programming/data management. New to the web development scene and javascript. Have been having a lot of fun exploring the plethora of npm modules available for server-side and client-side development. As I explore these modules and experiment with them in my code I'm noticing a recurring difficulty.

As a concrete example, I've just inserted the Browserify npm module into a node.js web app. The documentation for Browserify suggests to use it like so:

```
var brow = browserify(__dirname + '/client_js/main.js', {debug:true});
brow.bundle(function(err, buf){ ... });
```

A common problem that I encounter when using npm modules is that I cannot tell at a glance whether a module function is asynchronous or not. In this case, I would assume that browserify() is async, because I'm passing in a file path and I assume the function will read that filepath, which would put some todo's on the event loop. On the other hand, browserify() does not accept a callback function, which suggests it's not async?

Assuming that browserify() is async, how can I be sure that all the events it puts on the event loop are completed before I call brow.bundle() on the next line?

In this instance and in many other cases with npm modules, I am left wondering whether the module function will complete before I depend on the results later in the script. Is there a way to tell? If the only solution is to read the module source, that's fair, but it introduces a heavy burden for adopting new modules.

I am aware of an npm module that attempts to help with this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-async-function. Is this the best solution available?

Comment: See [How to determine if a function is asynchronous programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000772/node-js-how-to-programmatically-determine-asynchronous/29000806#29000806)

Comment: @jfriend00 's link is dead-on.  The module you linked is doing a best guess, but is not foolproof.  If the function returns a `Promise`, it is a solid bet it is async, but it is possible that they instead opted for a callback pattern.  Your best bet is to simply read the documentation.  Also, when looking around at various npm modules, remember to be discerning-- look on Github for the number of stars, open issues, closed issues, last update, etc-- a lot of packages out there are simply pet projects long abandoned, and don't represent mature, production ready software.

Comment: Just to echo that *"Your best bet is to simply **read the documentation**"*. You're not talking about evaluating some code at runtime for this case, so it really comes down to the documentation. The documentation for methods will generally either 1. return a Promise 2. show a callback as the optional last argument. Another good "rule of thumb" is to essentially ask *"Does this do any I/O?"* as in Disk, Network  etc. If the answer is yes ( i.e Talks to database == Network ) then the function is almost certainly async, and thus returns a Promise or takes a callback.

Comment: Also at the risk of "advocacy", there are things like TypeScript which are meant to obviate such problems, as the function signature is always ( meant to be ) available. It's not a must, but you might consider looking into that.